# jQuery v2.1.0 conflict not click on button

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, woocommerce

I have Jquery conflict on only **Checkout Page -> Review & Payment**

You can see on [site](https://jsdentallab.com/my-account/checkout/)

**Pay with Amazon** button Pop up on new window. as **CART** page already work.

[image]

Can suggest me proper solution.

Thank You.

Comment: How can you say that it's a `jQuery` conflict?

Comment: @Dhaval: Yes it comes dynamically  I have check inspect element Console

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons/controls in a popup are created dynamically, so you may try delegating `click` event using [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Try

```
$(document.body).on("click",".pay_with_amazon > img",function(){
    //your rest of code goes here
});
```

*Syntax:*

```
$(closestparentelement).on('event','targetselector',function(){
    // code
});
```